# filtering phonecall view according to incident statecode

Tags: dynamics-crm, view, filtering, dynamics-crm-2016

I am working with Dynamics CRM 2016 and I want to filter my phonecall (vanila entity) view according to incident(vanila entity) statecode, when I try to set my filtering with crm UI, incident- *statecode* is not shown as an option to filter by, can I do it with crm UI? or must use code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am able to do this. Is this what you are looking for?

[image]